# How to give current iteration in foreach inside template tag in odoo

Tags: odoo

How to know the number of current iteration in `foreach` inside template without create new variable to stock iteration number? I can't use examples in odoo documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/qweb.html#reference-qweb 
For example:

```
$as_all
    the object being iterated over
$as_value
    the current iteration value, identical to $as for lists and integers, but for mappings it provides the value (where $as provides the key)
$as_index
    the current iteration index (the first item of the iteration has index 0)
$as_size
    the size of the collection if it is available
$as_first
    whether the current item is the first of the iteration (equivalent to $as_index == 0)
$as_last
    whether the current item is the last of the iteration (equivalent to $as_index + 1 == $as_size), requires the iteratee’s size be available
```

Comment: What about index?

Comment: can you give me example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably missed this part [from the docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/qweb.html#loops):

> `$as` will be replaced by the name passed to `t-as`

Example:

```
<t t-foreach="some_list" t-as="var_name">
  <p> I'm in loop <t t-esc="var_name_index"/></p>
</t>
```

Comment: and how can I use that index as an attribute on the same line as the foreach ? Meaning something like: `<div t-foreach="list" t-as="item" t-att-index="item_index">...</div>` it doesn't seem to be working (the attribute it's missing in the output)

Comment: Just wrap the `<div>` inside a `<t t-foreach...`

Comment: maybe my example with a DIV was wrong, actually I needed it inside an XML with strict XSD, but of course I could have used the same approach. In the end I've found a much better solution: `<XMLTag t-foreach="records" t-as="record" t-att-line="'%s' % record_index">...</XMLTag>`

Comment: The XSD shouldn't be a problem because it should care only about the final XML produced by the QWeb template, and `<t>` tags are stripped out from that result.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's why I've stated that "I could have used the same approach", but in the end I did find another working solution without wrapping it in a simple `<t>` tag